# How to add an attribute to an image with a specific class or alt text js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I need to add an attribute to specific images by using JS or jQuery, but I can't figure it out.

I'm using WordPress and the images that I want to add the attribute are inside a slider, so I cannot add any class to those images.

I tried to add the attribute that I want by using the container class to find images, but it didn't work.

```
$('.dce-img > img').attr('rlskip', '1');
```

This how I want it to be:

```
<div class="dce-item">
  <figure data-image-ratio="0.5" class="dce-img dce-fit-img">
    <img src="../img/F4D13DA3-5351-4F69-8C33-0A1EF3BFDF67.webp"  alt="Demo_ts_2" rlskip="1"> 
  </figure>
</div>
```

Can you help me to find a solution please? I have to add the `rlskip` attribute to the images of the slider here.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask], then revise to show the relevant code here. It's not adequate to link to it. All we really need is the bit of HTML involved. Also, please tag jQuery if you're looking for jQuery solutions. WordPress is probably irrelevant unless you're working with its PHP backend.

Comment: Be wary of adding non-standard attributes in to your HTML. It will make it invalid so it fails WCAG testing and may cause issues in the rendering of the HTML or the behaviour of JS. If you want to add custom metadata to an element, use a `data-*` attribute instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$` is not defined.  Change `$` to `jQuery` like below:

```
jQuery('.dce-img > img').attr('rlskip', '1');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answear
I already tried, but it did't work

Comment: hmmm worked for me when I added it via dev tools.